# Laravel 5.6 envoy error when called from controller

Tags: homebrew, laravel-valet, laravel-envoy

I'm trying to use envoy from laravel to call some scripts on my server.
Right now I'm doing it with a virtual machine installed on my mac.

I'm trying to run my envoy scripts from a controller as follow:

```
function __construct()
{
    $command = "/Users/test_user/.composer/vendor/bin/envoy run test --filename=new_folder"

    $process = new Process($command);
    $process->start();

    foreach ($process as $type => $data) {
        if ($process::OUT === $type) {
            echo "\nRead from stdout: ".$data;
        } else { // $process::ERR === $type
            echo "\nRead from stderr: ".$data;
        }
    }
    exit();
}
```

Now when let this run I get the following response:

```
Read from stdout: Valet requires Homebrew to be installed on your Mac.
```

If I open my terminal and run: which brew

```
which brew
/usr/local/bin/brew
```

and my $PATH

```
/Users/test_user/Android/platform-tools:/Users/test_user/Android/tools:~/.composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin alias numFiles='echo 14'
```

I'm not exactly sure why this seems to fail?

Valet was installed with the `composer global require laravel/valet` command, and was not installed locally for the project.

Is there any way of fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

You should install envoy locally in your project:

`composer require laravel/envoy`

and execute it from vendor/bin/envoy.

Also don't forget to set the working directory for the process to base path, assuming your `Envoy.blade.php` is in the root path of your app.

```
function __construct()
{
  $command = base_path('vendor/bin') . "/envoy run test --filename=new_folder"

  $process = new Process($command);
  $process->setWorkingDirectory(base_path());
  $process->start();

  foreach ($process as $type => $data) {
    if ($process::OUT === $type) {
        echo "\nRead from stdout: ".$data;
    } else { // $process::ERR === $type
        echo "\nRead from stderr: ".$data;
    }
  }
  exit();
}
```